# Using "Git externals" with Subversion?

Tags: windows, svn, git, tortoisesvn

I recently had occasion to add a dependency on a Git-hosted project to a Subversion-hosted one.  After adding support for an ad-hoc `git:externals`
property to the parent project's packaging script to manage this dependency, it occurred to me that someone may have found such a property handy before and that it would be awfully nice if the project's developers didn't have to perform their Git checkouts/updates separately.  :-)

Unfortunately, my Google searches have yet to turn up such a tool, if it exists.  Has anyone heard of such a thing?  A Subversion client which, based on the metadata stored in a repository, can perform non-Subversion checkouts?  As far as I'm aware, there's generally no such thing as a "post-checkout hook", which I suspect would make this non-trivial to implement without a custom Subversion client, so I'm still hoping such a tool already exists.  We primarily use TortoiseSVN on Windows as a client, but suggestions for any tool/platform are welcome.

Comment: Only thought I have is to use git-svn to pull the git dependency into a svn repository of your own and then add a standard svn external for that.

Comment: I had the same thought, but in the end I think I'd prefer continuing to manage the Git checkouts separately to maintaining my own mirror of the Git project.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it all works, but I just got all this working today. I have TortoiseSVN and TortoiseGit installed, and I can set up an external reference to a GitHub repo right in my SVN repo. Unfortunately I can't merge from that external repo, but at least I only need do a single update on my working copy and I should easily notice if there are changes updating from GitHub.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this solution. With git-svn you at least have something that was designed to do this, what you have now seems to me works only by accident. Right?